# MISRA C-2012 Rule 10.3 Violation?

Tags: c, type-conversion, boolean, misra

When I try to add these macros:

```
#define BOOT_VD_TRUE  ((uint8_t)(0x00U))
#define BOOT_VD_FALSE ((uint8_t)(0x01U))
```

It violates MISRA C-2012 Rule 10.3: `Implicit conversion of (uint8_t)1U from essential type "boolean" to different or narrower essential type "unsigned 8-bit int"`.

I tried removing type cast but still it considers 0 and 1 as booleans and not integers.

Function Definition is as follows:

```
uint8_t bootInitFlag(uint8_t Val) 
{ 
   uint8_t bootFlag = Val;
   // Doing something
}

bootInitFlag(BOOT_VD_TRUE);
```

Comment: No idea about MISRA but `((uint8_t)(whatever))` will be immediately promoted to `int` anyway.

Comment: You will have to show where they are used that triggers the warning.

Comment: The implication from the nomenclature `BOOT_VD_TRUE` is that you *are* using them as booleans. Show the usage: a macro itself isn't error-forming (apart from syntax).

Comment: What type do you use to represent the boolean parameter? `_Bool`? In that case, try cast the constant to it rather than `uint8_t`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question if you add new information. This is not a forum.

Comment: Just a guess ... Did you try: `#define BOOT_VD_TRUE  ((uint8_t)0x00U)` or `#define BOOT_VD_TRUE  ((uint8_t)0x00)`

Comment: It makes no sense that `0x00` and `0x01` would be considered "essential type boolean". They're perfectly normal integers, which just happen to also be the values of booleans.

Comment: I just tried this with a well-known commercial lint-style tool (using MISRA 2012 rules), and it doesn't make this complaint. You should contact your vendor - it looks like you have a very trivial example you could share with them.

Comment: Removing TRUE and FALSE from the macro definition worked :) Thanks, Everyone!

Answer (score 1):

In order for any MISRA checker to work as intended, it needs to know what your boolean types are. Normally they are `bool`, `true`, `false` unless you are stuck with ancient C90. In that case you need to actively tell the tool what your boolean types are or it can't know that.

A tool which *assumes* that some of your types are essentially boolean based on the naming is just broken. Bug report it.

Answer (score 0):

As Lundin states in his answer, this appears to be a tool configuration issue... talk to your vendor.

--

But... noting your code:

```
#define BOOT_VD_TRUE  ((uint8_t)(0x00U))   /* ADB notes: TRUE  = 0 */
#define BOOT_VD_FALSE ((uint8_t)(0x01U))   /* ADB notes: FALSE = 1 */
```

I assume your specifying of `TRUE = 0` and `FALSE = 1` is intentional? But guaranteed to confuse the heck out of most people... so I **strongly** advocate using the traditional `false = 0, true = 1`

--

However...

You don't specify which version of C or which compiler you are using, but unless you are still using a fully-conformant C90-only compiler, the recommendation has to be to use `<stdbool.h>` (and even in the era of C90, most compilers had adopted the proposed `<stdbool.h>` as a extension):

And even if you insist on using the intermediate names, you can use:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

#define BOOT_VD_TRUE  false    // ADB notes: reverse logic retained
#define BOOT_VD_FALSE true     // ADB notes: reverse logic retained

void bootInitFlag( bool Val )  // ADB notes: void, as you're not returning anything
{ 
   bool bootFlag = Val;
   // Doing something
}

...

bootInitFlag( BOOT_VD_TRUE );
```